# What does Superman's black symbol mean in "Kingdom Come"?

Tags: dc, superman, costume, kingdom-come

In the *Kingdom Come* miniseries, does Superman's black symbol mean anything?

[image: Superman with his hands together down across his body looking down, his normal S symbol is red but with a black background. Other superheroes in the background are looking at him]

Answer (score 6):

During funerals, people wear black.  When a fellow officer dies, police wear black stripes across their badges.  This is similar.

After the death of

> Lois Lane,

and seeing the world embrace the newer, more violent heroes like Magog, Superman entered a sort of mourning for how the world and his life used to be.  So he changed the background color of his S-shield, and changed the color of his belt.  This replaced the brightest colors of his outfit with black.

Answer (score 5):

Over the years Superman's symbol changed a lot but I believe that Alex Ross who created miniseries *Kingdom Come* re-imagined the "electric" emblem with color scheme used in 1939 comics and 1941 animated series. So black and red color scheme is not something new but borrowed from 1939. I have never managed to find why they used those colors back then.

[image: A list of Superman's different chest S symbols across the years in the comics and in popular culture; those with the black background are from the comics: 1939, 1996 (Kingdom Come) and 2001 inspired by Kingdom Come. From Popular Culture: 1941]